# MySQL: Between Dates on two date fields

Tags: php, sql

I have two fields with stores a particular date-range of an event.

Let's say and event will start at 12/13/12 - 12/20/12.

So our fields are

Name:My Event
Start_at: 12/13/12
End_at: 12/20/12

the user will have two input box. One box will state the from_date and the other to_date. If the user selects

from_date: 12/15/12
to_date:   12/19/12

it should display the 'my event` record since it falls into the date_range.

Question: How do you go about this in SQL?

Comment: The question is too simple. Google it

Comment: It's also too broad: different database technologies use different code to accomplish this. You should specify what database you're using (i.e. MySQL).

Comment: Seriously just type "mysql select between date range" in google....

Comment: If it's a simple BETWEEN, I would not asked it here as I already know that.

Comment: Are your date columns actually of some DATETIME type or just Varchar(something)? If they are indeed strings - then your DB is comparing them as strings and you are not getting the expected results.

Answer (score 1):

it depends on how you keep the date data in database

if it is a 'datetime' field use 'between' construction

```
mysql_query("select * from events where date between '".date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($from_date))."' and ".date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime($to_date)));
```

i can't make exact query because i dunno field names in table and your parameter names in query

i hope you understood the idea

Comment: there are two fields ... start_date and end_date.

Answer (score 0):

as for my experience. date in INT datatype is lighter than datetime datatype on the mysql database, 
you can try changing the datetime to INT first, then before saving it on the database you can convert it to seconds, say:

```
<?php
 $start_at = strtotime("12/13/12");
 $end_at = strtotime("12/20/12");
/* SAVE on the database */
?>
```

then save it on the table date field with INT datatype

then on the query, you can easily say

if the user inputs from_date: 12/15/12 to_date: 12/19/12 on the two fields (start and end field)

```
<?php
 $start_at = strtotime($from_date); //12/15/12
 $end_at = strtotime($to_date); //12/19/12
/*do the query*/
 mysql_query("SELECT name FROM table WHERE Start_at <= '$start_at' AND End_at >= '$end_at'");
?>
```

I didnt complete the script but the idea is there, hope you get it.